# Pattern Replacing in string with escaped characters failing with replaceAll

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I have a use case where I want to replace some values in html string, so I need to do replaceAll for that, but that is not working, although replace is working fine, here is my code:

```
    String str  = "<style type=\"text/css\">#include(\"Invoice_Service_Tax.css\")</style>";
    String pattern = "#include(\"Invoice_Service_Tax.css\")";
    System.out.println(str.replace(pattern, "some-value"));
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll(pattern, "some-value"));
```

output is :

```
<style type="text/css">some-value</style>
<style type="text/css">#include("Invoice_Service_Tax.css")</style>
```

For my use case I need to do replaceAll only, I tried with below patterns also but no help:

```
"#include(\\\"Invoice_Service_Tax.css\\\")"
"#include(Invoice_Service_Tax.css)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace doesn't look for special chars, just a literal replace while `replaceAll` uses regexes so there are some special characters.

The problem with the regex is that `(` is a special character for grouping so you need to escape it.

`#include\\(\"Invoice_Service_Tax.css\"\\)` should work with your `replaceAll`

Answer (score 1):

The key difference between `String.replace` and `String.replaceAll` is that the first parameter for `String.replace` is `string literal`, but for `String.replaceAll` it is a `regex`. [java doc of those two methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) has great explanation about it. So if there's special chars like `\` or `$` in the string which you want to replace, you'll see the different behaves again, like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str  = "<style type=\"text/css\">#include\"Invoice_Service_Tax\\.css\"</style>";
    String pattern = "#include\"Invoice_Service_Tax\\.css\"";
    System.out.println(str.replace(pattern, "some-value")); // works
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll(pattern, "some-value")); // not works, pattern should be: "#include\"Invoice_Service_Tax\\\\.css\""
}
```